# Is there a bounded non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that stays fixed under a non-identity translation?

Tags: geometry

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and consider the space $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $S$ is a non-empty and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $f$ be a non-identity translation of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I conjecture that the image $f(S)$ is never the same set as $S$. Is this true, and if so, what is the proof?

Comment: Have you tried proving this yourself for a special case, e.g. $n=2$ and $f$ is translation along the $x$-axis? The general case is no harder.

Comment: My instinct is to prove it by contradiction. Suppose $S$ is non-empty and bounded. Write down exactly what your function $f$ does and suppose that $f(S) = S$. There's basically only like one or two things you can say next.

Comment: Hint: take some $s \in S$. What can you say about $\{s, f(s), f(f(s)), \ldots\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume otherwise. If $f(S)=S$ then $f^n(S)=S$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Since $S$ is bounded we can choose some $s_0 \in S$ and construct a disk $D$ centered at $s_0$ so that $S \subset D$ and say it has diameter $d$.

Now since the translation is non-trivial we have that $\vert f(s)-s\vert > 0$ and that $f^n(s)-s=n(f(s)-s)$. By Archimedes principle there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N(f(s_0)-s_0) > d$ and so $f^N(s_0) \notin D$, and therefore not in $S$, a contradiction.